# Javascript import failing in react native for android release build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Inside a const folder there are three files `index.js`, `package.json` and `sample.js`
**index.js**

```
export const FOO = {
  RENEWAL: 2,
...
};
export const BAR = {
  ITEM: 2,
...
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "@const",
    "description": "All the constants like colors, string, product id, their title etc"
}
```

**sample.js**

```
import {FOO, BAR} from '.';

export const someFunc = () => {
 const test = FOO.RENEWAL;
}
```

This code was working fine for past 1 year. 
 In RELEASE mode it suddenly started throwing error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'RENEWAL' of undefined`
But running in DEBUG mode and using VSCode IntelliSense doesn't throw any error and is able to identify correct value.

Its working fine on replacing with the below import statement

`import {FOO, BAR} from '@const';`

Why did `import {FOO, BAR} from '.';` suddenly stop working?
Also is there any difference between

1. import using `'.'`
2. import using `'@const'`
3. import using `'./index'`
4. Using `module.exports`
5. Defining an export like

```
const FOO = {...}
const BAR = {...}
export {
  FOO,
  BAR,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do a practice of defining the correct path always because after some release it will change its behavior.

> Is there a difference between those 5?

There are no differences in `export default {}` & `export const` but defining `.` this will create problems in the future and about `@const`, there is no way of defining like this except you are using custom webpack config.

The correct way is `./` or I will suggest you to use `/index` because its shows the file and easy to read

Comment: Since eslint wasn't throwing any error did miss out on the path being undefined. In react native custom path does works and custom webpack isn't needed. My main question is why did import from '.' suddenly stop working which has been working for past 1 year without any errors. Have updated the same in question.

Comment: `.` is usually works fine in Linux systems, not in windows systems. About why it's not working now, for that you need to ask developers of RN by creating GitHub issue, they will answer you

Answer (score -1):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What's your point? Why did you posted this code?